# How to perform update operation using CriteriaUpdate in sping Data JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

As spring data JPA provide specification to get result like below

```
public static Specification<Customer> customerHasBirthday() {
    return new Specification<Customer> {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.get(Customer_.birthday), today);
        }
    };
}
```

and then we can pass above specification in repository method `customerRepository.findAll(customerHasBirthday);` Now I want to perform update operation using criteria update in spring data JPA like below

```
public static Specification<Customer> upadteCustomerName() {
    return new Specification<Customer> {
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            CriteriaUpdate<Customer> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Customer.class)
            update.set("name", "newName");
            return update.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("id"), 2));
        }
    };
}
```

Obviously I will get compile time error as

> CriteriaUpdate can not be converted into predicate

Is spring data JPA provide any easy way to implement CriteriaUpdate and then directly pass the instance to Repository method like in Get operation we have `findAll()` method?

or is there any other best way to implement criteriaUpdate in spring Data JPA?

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504562/11733759
You can do it with `entityManager.createQuery(update)`

Comment: pls, don't use quote format for non-quote paragraphs. I corrected that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504562/11733759) you can do like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Customer> q = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Customer.class);
Root<Customer> root = q.from(Customer.class);
q.set(root.get("name"),  "newName")
        .where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("id"), 2)); 

int result = em.createQuery(q).executeUpdate();
```