BeanUtils.copyProperties overrides whole object
I have a ServiceDAO(model) which has around 30 fields, where I have serviceId as primary key.
The incoming request is ServiceDTO which can have any of the 30 fields which has to be updated based on a non-primary key.
So I am doing a findByNonPrimaryKey which returns List
I am iterating each element of DAO and calling serviceRepo.save()
Before calling the save, I am calling BeanUtils.copyProperties to copy the null values in the DTO object with the values from the DB and retain the modified values and save.
The issue is, The DTO object is getting overidden with the 1st iterated object and the next iteration doesn't have any null and keeps updating the same object .
Is there any other way I can handle this or retain the old value while copy is called?
I tried to create a new DTO object and assign to it, still it is overriding it.
Also tried with MapStruct, that did not work.
example:

one DTO which has values to update and that may have multiple entries in DB
Like the query looks like
 update SuperUser set SET  status =  'COMPLETE',  workflow_Status= 'PENDING'  WHERE sap_ID = 1;
where DTO has status and workflow status
and SuperUser with sap_id =1 can have multiple entries, I have to update all the entries in DB with sap_id =1>
The problem here is with setting the values, because the DTO value may have different fields not just the status and workflow status


You have one DTO and multiple DB objects and you want to keep multiple DB objects data to one DTO object?

No, one DTO which has values to update and that may have multiple entries in DB
Like the query looks like
update SuperUser set SET  status =  'COMPLETE',  workflow_Status= 'PENDING'  WHERE sap_ID = 1;
where DTO has status and workflow status
and SuperUser with sap_id =1 can have multiple entries, I have to update all the entries in DB with sap_id =1
The problem here is with setting the values, because the DTO value may have different fields not just the status and workflow status

If you want to create a custom query based on the DTO fields, you can use CriteriaBuilder to create a dynamic update query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874116/how-to-perform-update-operation-using-criteriaupdate-in-sping-data-jpa
